# Shell script to push code from linux to git by update instead of overwrite

Tags: git, shell, sh

I am currently trying to create a shell script push my code to github. However, i am not familiar with git command.

My Target:
The shell script to push code from several linux folders to github through git with following criteria:

- create file in git if empty
- update (instead of overwrite) if there are any difference in between
- Delete if files no longer exist in folder (delete record can be found in git)

Thus, I write following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo rm -r .git

git init

CurrentTS=`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`
echo "$CurrentTS"
cd `dirname $0`
ROOT_PATH=`pwd`

echo $ROOT_PATH

git rm -r --cached .
git remote remove origin

git add ./Folder1
git add ./Folder2/*.cfg
git add ./Folder3/dags/

echo "$CurrentTS"

#echo `git status`
git commit -m `date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`
git remote add origin 'https://<username>:<password>@github.com/<myaccountname>/<Repository>.git'
git push -f origin master

exit 0
```

However, it can only drop original image and overwrite previous version instead of show the updates. May i get some hints on what shall i google search to work "keeping update record"

Comment: Could you modify this to be focused on a specific problem you have, rather than effectively being a request for someone to write a different script that behaves to your specifications? (Yes, you're showing code, but your question is not something that asks how to solve a specific bug in that code, but more of a request for someone to write a completely different script to replace it).

Answer (score 1):

I think the proplem is, you are deleting the whole .git instead of maybe synchronizing with git pull.

The solution could be:

```
#!/bin/sh

git pull # when you need synchronizing else remove

CurrentTS=`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`
echo "$CurrentTS"
cd `dirname $0`
ROOT_PATH=`pwd`

echo $ROOT_PATH

git rm -r --cached .

git add ./Folder1
git add ./Folder2/*.cfg
git add ./Folder3/dags/

echo "$CurrentTS"

#echo `git status`
git commit -m `date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`
git push -f origin master

exit 0
```

Comment: This code would benefit from being run through http://shellcheck.net/ and addressing the issues found.

Comment: Hey, just using what the answer provides

Comment: "fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository" if no "git remote add origin"

Comment: I think he has it configured already, when he uses rm -r .git in the first line